# How to add two triggers to one custom button

Tags: custom-button

How to add Two Triggers for one custom button in the same object?
I Have Two Triggers A,B. A trigger Performing Field Updation In the same object where B trigger performing field Updation of another Object.now I want to create a Button,when i click the button then the Two performance should be happen ?
How to do?
// trigger Code

trigger DealSheetUpddate on Change_Log__c(before insert ,before update ,after Update){

```
ChangeLogTriggerHandler.UpdateOfSameObject(newlist, oldlist) ;
ChangeLogTriggerHandler.UpdateOnAnotherObject(newlist, oldlist);
    }
```

thanks in Adavnce.....
// trigger handler

public class ChangeLogTriggerHandler {

```
public void UpdateOfSameObject(List<Change_Log__c> newlist,List<Change_Log__c> oldlist){

    for(Change_Log__c c: newlist){

    c.CP_ZIP_Code__c= c.CPs_ZIP_Code__c;
    c.Fixed_Price__c=c.Fixed_Prices__c;
    c.Broker__c=c.Brokers__c;
    c.Amended_Version__c=c.Amended_Versions__c;
    c.Amended_Verssion_Sent_To_CP__c=c.Amended_Verssions_Sent_To_CP__c;
    c.Broker_s_Name__c=c.Broker_s_Names__c;
    c.Brokerage_Per_MMBTU__c=c.Brokerages_Per_MMBTU__c;
    c.BU_Contract__c=c.BU_Contracts__c;
    c.Buy_Sell__c=c.Buys_Sells__c;
    c.Confirmation_Email_Sent__c=c.Confirmations_Email_Sent__c;
    c.Counter_Party__c=c.Counter_Partys_Name__c;
    c.CP_Addres__c=c.CP_Address__c;
    c.CP_Address_Line1__c=c.CPs_Address_Line1__c;
    c.CP_Address_Line2__c=c.CPs_Address_Line2__c;
    c.CP_Confirm_Email__c=c.CP_Confirms_Email__c;
    c.CP_ZIP_Code__c=c.CPs_ZIP_Code__c;
    c.End_Date__c=c.End_Dates__c;
    c.External_Comments__c=c.External_Commentss__c;
    c.Instrument__c=c.Instruments__c;
    c.Internal_Comments__c=c.Internal_Commentss__c;
    c.Internal_Trader__c=c.Internal_Traders__c;
    c.Link_ID__c=c.Link_IDs__c;
    c.Meter_Name__c=c.Meter_Names__c;
    c.NG_Pipe_Name__c=c.NG_Pipe_Names__c;
    c.Price__c=c.Prices__c;
    c.Price_Type__c=c.Price_Types__c;
    c.PriceIndex__c=c.PriceIndex_Names__c;
    c.ReSend_Email__c=c.ReSend_Emails__c;
    c.Start_Date__c=c.Start_Dates__c;
    c.Strategy__c=c.Strategys__c;
    c.Terms_Condition__c=c.Terms_Conditions__c;
    c.Total_Volume__c=c.Total_Volumes__c;
    c.Trade_Date__c=c.Trade_Dates__c;
    c.Tradebook__c=c.Tradebooks__c;
    c.Vlm_Day__c=c.Volume_MMBTU_Per_Days__c;

}

}
```

public void UpdateOnAnotherObject( List newlist,List oldlist){

```
Set<String> names = new Set<String>();
List<Dealsheet__c> dealSheetList = new List<Dealsheet__c>();


for(Change_Log__c cLog : newlist){
    names.add(cLog.Name);
}

Map<String,Dealsheet__c> DealSheet = new map<String,Dealsheet__c>();

for(Dealsheet__c deals : [Select Name,CP_P_O_CODE__c, Vlm_Day__c  from Dealsheet__c where name IN: names ]){
      DealSheet.put(deals.name, deals);
}  

for(Change_Log__c log : newlist){

     Dealsheet__c dSheet = DealSheet.get(log.Name);

     if( dSheet!=null){


      //dSheet.CP_P_O_CODE__c = log.CPs_ZIP_Code__c;
      //dSheet.Fixed_Price__c =log.Fixed_Prices__c;   
      dsheet.Vlm_Day__c=log.Volume_MMBTU_Per_Days__c;   
      dealSheetList.add(dSheet);
       System.Debug('dSheet**** ' + dSheet);  
    }         
}

    }

}
```

Comment: You should have only [one trigger per object](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices).

Comment: we can use trigger handler..in the scripting of a button we can put only one handler na

Answer (score 0):

You should merge the code of trigger in one Trigger Handler class.

Please create two methods in Trigger Handler and call those methods in a Sequence.

**Handler Code:**

```
public class TriggerHandler{

public void method1(){
// Field update on Same object
}

public void method2(){
// Field update on another object
}

}
```

**Trigger Code:**

```
Trigger sample on Opportunity (Before Insert){

//Calling Handler Methods

TriggerHandler tHandler = new TriggerHandler ();
tHandler.method1();
tHandler.method2();

}
```

Comment: thanks shanu...that is my trigger handler and trigger code gvng error as varaible doesnot exisist:newlist

Comment: Replace "newlist" with Trigger.new

Comment: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: ChangeLogTriggerHandler.UpdateOfSameObject(List<Change_Log__c>)

Answer (score 0):

Triggers fire when DML is performed, not when a button is pressed. You can write a trigger to do many things on other objects that are related with data from a record on a different object, but it must be triggered based on DML actions from the existing object.

You can include the logic for more than one "action" in the same trigger. When you don't include them in the same trigger, you have no control over which trigger fires first. After one trigger fires, the other trigger fires. Then workflow fires. That causes both triggers to fire again a 2nd time in any order. Workflow then runs again one last time. This is not at all an efficient way to handle have your triggers operate.

The logic for triggers can be ordered in many different ways. I recommend you work through the [Trailhead Module on Apex Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/apex_triggers) which explains this in much more detail than I can here.